# Complete groovy list of parameters

Tags: list, groovy, parameters

I have a function with an optional list of parameters :

```
cleanFolders(String... folders) {
    other_function_called(param1,param2,param3)
}
```

This function calls another function which take exactly three parameters.

So, I want to use the list of parameters **folders** to call this other function :

- if there is only one element in folders list, I call

```
other_function_called(folders[0],"none","none")
```

- if there are two elements :

```
other_function_called(folders[0],folders[1],"none")
```

- and for three elements :

```
other_function_called(folders[0],folders[1],folders[2])
```

How I can do this properly (not using many disgracious "if else") ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Jeff writes, you can use `*` to unpack the varargs array.

However, this will give you `MissingMethodException` if the number of arguments is not matching.

For this case you could create a new array starting with the available values, that is then filled up with the remaining default values, so that unpacked it just matches the right number of arguments.

```
def spreadArgs = args + ["none"] * (3 - args.size())
other_function_called(*spreadArgs)
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarity.  I removed my answer.

Comment: thanks! So it doesn't get lost, this is the link you posted with details on the spreading operator: https://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_spreading_method_arguments

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I need !

Comment: If you define `otherArgs` with something like `def otherArgs = folders + ['none'] * (3 - folders.size())`, then I think you could simplify `other_function_called(*folders, *otherArgs)` to `other_function_called(*otherArgs)`.

Comment: good suggestion, it looks simpler & cleaner! I updated the answer

Comment: That what I've done, indeed :) Thanks all.

Comment: Awesome.  The code will throw an exception if `args` ever has more than 3 elements in it.  It may be that you know that will never happen.  If you wanted to guard against that you could check the size first, or you could do something like `def spreadArgs = (args + ["none", "none", "none"]).take(3)`.  If you know the incoming data will never have more than 3 elements, the original thing is probably fine.

Comment: Good idea, I will take this too. Thanks again Jeff.